# iPhone: NavigationController NavigationBar Back button text

Tags: iphone, button, navigationcontroller

When I push a new ViewController onto a navigation controller stack the "back" button is the Title of the previous controller.

How can I change the text in the back button to "Back" instead of the default name-of-last-controller?

Comment: Just know that this is frowned upon by Apple's iPhone interface guidelines. (Though admittedly needed when titles run long.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually set the title on the main view controller's `navigationItem`'s title. Basically each `UIViewController` has a little stub `UINavigationItem` which contains metadata about how that view should be referenced inside a `UINavigationController`. By default, that metadata just falls back to the `UIViewController` itself.

Assuming 'self' is the `UIViewController` of the view that's visible inside the `UINavigationController`, set:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Custom Title"
```

Comment: This not only makes the buttons title "My Custom Title" but it also makes the previous page in the Navigation Stack's title "My Custom Title".

Answer (score 27):

This is the proper way to make a back button with something other than the previous' pages title

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
barButton.title = @"Your Title";

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Its to my understanding that:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

will make the Title of the navigation bar on the previous page this which is not what you want.

Answer (score 13):

I know, the question is very old, but I found a nice solution.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
barButton.title = @"back";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Works from childView! Tested with iOS 7.

Answer (score 10):

You need to create a custom button on the navigation controller. Put the following code in the *viewDidLoad* in your Root View Controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem * tempButtonItem = [[[ UIBarButtonItem alloc] init] autorelease];
tempButtonItem .title = @"Back";

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = tempButtonItem ;
```

By setting the navigation bar button on the Root View Controller, the pushed view shows the appropriate back button.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the title of the current view controller of the navigation controller before push the new view controller:

```
self.title = @"Custom Title";

[self pushViewController: newViewController ...];

and in the navigation controller's delegate class

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

if([viewController class] == [OldViewController class]) {

viewController.title = @"Your previous title";

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the Back button title in the originating controller's "viewWillDisappear" function as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //Set Title for this view
        self.navigationItem.title = "My Title"

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //Set Title for back button in next view 
        self.navigationItem.title = "Back"
}
```